# Is there a way to utilize something like Docker labels in Helm charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

In docker we can add labels. These are metadata to Docker objects. Then, these labels can be queried/read at runtime by fetching the `manifest.json` before starting a container.

I was wondering if we have a similar mechanism in Helm?

**Workflow**

1. Build my app (multiple .jar files)
2. Create multiple Docker images
3. Scan the images for vulnerabilities and add a custom label (image-safe = true/false) based on the result of scan
4. Create a helm Chart
5. Publish the chart to a chart repository.

Later, if I want to install that chart I want to know if any containers referenced in the `Deployment.yaml` has this label `image-safe = false`. If it is set to false I either want to stop the installation of the chart or log a warning in my pipeline.

I know that I can open `.tgz` file read the `Deployment.ya ml` and look for the list of containers in it, retrieve the names and pull individual images down and check the labels BUT its too much.

Instead, if I can add some labels to the chart I can simply check those labels before running `helm install my-app my-app-chart.tgz` similar to the docker example I explained in the first paragraph.

Comment: Can you say a little more about the workflow you're hoping to have?  Helm charts' "native" formats are just gzipped tar files so you can interact with them fairly naturally, unlike Docker images, which don't really have a useful "native" format.  It might be helpful to see what your Docker-label-based workflow looks like and what you've tried to do to adapt it for Helm charts.

Comment: I updated my question. Hope its more clear now